# listing the data and the map moving when the data is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

My title may have made me sound like an idiot.
I just didnt know how to name what I want to do here.
I get the location of individuals data from my database in Json format.
Than using the marker clusterer jQuery plugin, these individuals are pin pointed on the map.
But I really like what they did on this website.
http://www.fetalhope.org/patients-families/treatment?cid=168&x=35&y=14

I will appreciate if you can help me build the same setting.
I am willing to pay as well, but unemployed dont expect much.
I am just trying to learn.

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "latitude": "22.3430194444444",
      "longitude": "114.110386111111"
    },
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "latitude": "48.4048403957642",
      "longitude": "2.68452644348145"
    }
  ]
}

        $(function CheckinMap() {
            $.when($.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "content/sewerage/index.cs.asp?Process=ViewMap"
            })).done(      function initialize(data) {
                var MapData = data;
                var center = new google.maps.LatLng(41.00527, 28.97696);
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('checkinmap'), {
                  zoom: 6,
                  center: center,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                  maxZoom: 14
                });
                var markers = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < MapData.users.length; i++) {
                  var location = MapData.users[i];
                  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.NIDLatitude,
                      location.NIDLongitude);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng
                  });
                  markers.push(marker);
                }
                var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of the api you are using (the example is for V3) of google maps what you can do is use the listener on the marker and when it's clicked you can get a value, let say an id, that identify the element you want to focus on the list.
So, assuming you have a marker, you can extend it and add your `id`.

```
var markerItem = new google.maps.Marker();
markerItem.metadata = {id: 1};
```

And then you add the event listener:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(markerItem, 'click', function () {
            var targetId = markerItem.get("id");
            //do something with the target id like scrolling the desired point of the list  

  });
```

Within the event you can the center the map to the lat/long of the clicked marker, create a new `infoWindow` and show it etc,,:

```
var infoWindowItem = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'Some content here!'});
infoWindowItem.open(map, markerItem);
```

Comment: Giorgio thanks a lot for the response but this is where confusing where do I put all this. I tried placing it inside the initialize(data) function but I received so many different errors.

Comment: try to reproduce the first example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events and start from there.